# Type error in Create of functions in python

Tags: python, function

```
def table(nb, max):
i = 0
while i < max:
    print((i+1)*nb)
    i += 1
print(table(nb=input('entree les valeur de nb '), max=input('entree les valeur 
de max')))
```

I tried to create a function to display the multiplication table, but I've got an error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert `max` and `nb` to integer: `while i < int(max)`, `print((i+1)*int(nb))`.

Here is the solution:

```
def table(nb, max):
    i = 0
    while i < int(max):
        print((i+1)*int(nb))
        i += 1


print(table(nb=input('entree les valeur de nb '), max=input('entree les valeur de max')))
```

Comment: This will cause a similar error for `nb` as well. Make sure to mention casting that parameter too

Comment: It will not cause an error, but will do a different thing without `nb` conversion to integer. I just misunderstood the problem description. I edited my post. Thank you ;)

Comment: Ah good point I forgot it actually repeats the string. But yeah, I think OP was intending for a multiplication

Comment: i did it and it corrected the problem but the code display that : entree les valeur de nb 8
entree les valeur de max 7
8
88
888
8888
88888
888888
8888888
None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You forget to correct also this line: `print((i+1)*int(nb))`. Without converting `nb` to integer, you are multiplying a string not a number with integer type.

Comment: thanks i corrected it and it works...thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Look at your error messages, it says you cannot compare between an `int` and a `str`. In this case, `i` has the value of an `int`, but `max` has the value of a `str`. This is because the function `input` returns a value of type `str`. You have to check if this value is appropriate and then cast it to a type `int`. The type cast will look like this: `max = int(max)`. Be careful though because this will raise an error if the value supplied by the user cannot be casted to an `int` (if they, for example, provide 'a' as the input, which cannot be casted to an `int`)

You could change the line from `while i < max:` to `while i < int(max)` or you could reassign the parameter `max` to `int(max)` before comparing to it. You will also have to do a similar cast for `nb`

By the way, the error here is not a "traceback error", it's a `TypeError`. A traceback shows you where the error occurred, and then *traces back* through your code to show where each function call happened leading up to this error.

Comment: i did it and it corrected the problem but the code display that : entree les valeur de nb 8
entree les valeur de max 7
8
88
888
8888
88888
888888
8888888
None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @alex.R can you please provide a snippet of your updated code as well as update your original question with code snippets rather than a link to an image?

Comment: thanks i corrected it and it works...thank you again

Answer (score 0):

We must declare the type of the variables as int

```
def table(nb,max):
i = 0
max=int(max)
nb=int(nb)
while i < max :
    print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
    i+=1

print(table(nb=input('entree les valeur de nb '), max=input('entree les valeur de max ')))
```